# "Error 438 Object does not support "with VBA-Selenium

Tags: vba, selenium

I am newbie and just try to finish my homework. I am trying to get the symbol, companyname, stock price from className by using VBA-Selenium in this website

https://www.barchart.com/stocks/indices/russell/russell2000?page=20&orderBy=lastPrice&orderDir=asc&viewName=main

but I am still getting the error

"Run time error '438'object doesn't support this property or method" with the line of code mysheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = mytables.FindElementByClass("symbol text-left").Text. How should I resolve this problem? I already tried to install new patch of Selenium but it was not working.

There is another problem, that this page has 20 pages and I have to click each page to take the stock price. How can I do this? Please help this poor student.

```
Public Sub Russelcrawler()
Dim driver As New WebDriver
Dim mytables As WebElements, table As WebElement, i As Integer, mysheet As Worksheet

With driver
    .Start "IE", "https://www.barchart.com/stocks/indices/russell/russell2000?page=20&orderBy=lastPrice&orderDir=asc&viewName=main"
    .Get "/"
End With


Set mysheet = Sheets("Russel")

Set mytables = driver.FindElementsByClass("bc-datatable")

i = 2
For Each table In mytables

mysheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = mytables.FindElementByClass("symbol text-left").Text
mysheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = mytables.FindElementByClass("symbolName text-left").Text
mysheet.Cells(i, 3).Value = mytables.FindElementByClass("lastPrice").Text

i = i + 1

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Does `FindElementByClass("symbol text-left")` return something?

Comment: Actually nothing, the error happened there